# How to Find the Interval Between Two Dates in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a 'test_date' column in 'test' table in Postgres DB, ex - (2018-05-29)

I need to calculate difference between current date and that date column and return the result as days, months, years.

I tried  -

```
select (current_date - test_date) from test;
```

but it returns the values as days. but I need the result as days, months, years.
How to convert it properly  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `timestamp` then you'll get a `interval' back:

```
select justify_interval(date_trunc('day', current_timestamp) - test_date)
```

The `date_trunc()` is there to set the time part of the timestamp to `00:00:00`. By default that would return an interval with only days in it. The `justify_interval()` will then "normalize" this to months, weeks and days.

E.g. `0 years 7 mons 28 days 0 hours 0 mins 0.0 secs`

Comment: Thank you so much! With this I can easily normalize the interval as per the requirement

Answer (score 2):

The [`age()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) function returns the value as an interval rather than the number of days:

```
select age(current_date, test_date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!